# Net angle force doesnt equal resultant velocity angle?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, physics

Here's the question I'm working on.

> A baseball with a mass of 0.152kg is moving horizontally at 32.0 m/s [E], when it is struck by a bat for 0.00200 seconds. The velocity of the ball just after the collision is 52.0 m/s [W 20° N].
>
> Find the impulse experienced by the ball and the average net force of the ball.

I have found the solution to be that the net force is 6292 N in the direction [W 12.4 N].

But I have a conceptual question: Why is it [W 12 N] if the resultant velocity after collision is [W 20 N]?? That doesn't make any sense! Why is it [W 20 N] when it has been affected by a net angle force of [W 12 N].

Comment: Imagine that instead of a bat you hit the ball with a feather, where the force due to the feather is still in the direction [W 12$^\circ$ N] but now of course the magnitude of the force is much less.  Would you expect the ball which is initially traveling [E] to turn almost completely around and start heading in the direction [W 12$^\circ$ N] after its been hit by the feather?  Probably not.  The direction of the force $\ne$ the direction of the resulting velocity in general.

Comment: I hope you don't mind but I edited your question mostly to remove the calculations which I did not deem to be relevant to your actual question.  If you disagree you can click the "edited [X time] ago" above my picture on your question and then click rollback over your last edit.

Comment: I added the calculations in case I had some oversight in the arithmetic. I understand it now: When the collision ceases and the ball goes airborne., the ball travels [W 20 N]. However, it still has a net force of [W 12 N], which means that the angle is being altered over time. The resultant velocity angle of one instance of time does not reflect the Net angle force, just like how the resultant velocity does not reflect the Net force.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine a ball rolling on a plane from left to right with constant speed. It's direction is $(1,0)$ (or $[E]$, if you prefer). Then nudge this ball from below - the direction of the force is $(0,1)$ (or $[N]$). What will happen the ball? It will continue to roll with velocity in the first quadrant ($[NE]$).

More conceptually, the force is *the change of momentum per unit of time*, therefore the direction of the force does no reflect the direction of the momentum itself, only of its evolution.

Comment: I do not completely understand. In your example, it makes sense because tan⁡θ=1/1=45, so it moves [NE]. But in this example, I solved for force and it gave me [W 12.4N], however the resultant velocity after the collision is [W 20 N]. Does that mean it starts off at [W 20 N], but because the net force it will eventually go to [W 12 N]?

Comment: No, the direction of the force is the change of impulse. Like with the example I gave - the direction of the force has nothing in common with the direction of the ball speed after the "nudge".